# C# to VB.Net Generic Delegate Error

Tags: c#, vb.net, generics, delegates

Firstly sorry about the title, wasn't quite sure what to put there.

**Background**
Need to call various methods on a service, but the service requires that we Login before every action call and then logout again.

SO instead of manually making 3 calls everytime, thought using a generic would be useful.

**The Code and the Problem**

In C#
Wrote a ServiceCaller Class

```
public class ServiceCaller<T>
{
    private T instance;

    public ServiceCaller(T param)
    {
        this.instance = param;
    }

    public void Call<U>(Func<T, U> aExpression, Action<U> returnClass)
    {
        Authentication authenticate = new Authentication();
        if (authenticate.Login())
        {
            U result = aExpression(this.instance);
            returnClass(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Then a class that has the actual implementation

```
public class MFMPlanActions
{
    public string GetPromotionPlans(PromotionPlan plan)
    {
        PromotionPlan plan = new Promotion()
        Do Stuff
        return plan
    }
}
```

and the webpage code behind does

```
var serviceWrapper = new ServiceTest.ServiceCaller<ServiceTest.MFMPlanActions> 
    (new ServiceTest.MFMPlanActions());
serviceWrapper.Call(x => x.GetPromotionPlans(plan), u => Console.WriteLine(u));
```

Works great in C# but in VB.net

The last bit doesn't work

The converted code is

```
Dim serviceWrapper = New API.ServiceCaller(Of API.MFMPlanActions)(New API.MFMPlanActions())
serviceWrapper.[Call](Function(x) x.GetPromotionPlans(plan), Function(u) Console.WriteLine(u))
```

On line

```
serviceWrapper.[Call](Function(x) x.GetPromotionPlans(plan), Function(u) Console.WriteLine(u))
```

I get: *Object reference not set to an instance of an object*

I am not familiar with VB.net enough to know where I am going wrong.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you sure `ServiceTest.ServiceCaller` is the same as `API.ServiceCaller`? It's the only difference I can see. Also, you probably want `Dim serviceWrapper As New` instead of `Dim serviceWrapper = New` there. Should not make a deal here, just a declaration standard in VB.NET.

Comment: Hi.Yeah they are the same, just renamed for actual project so that naming is better:)

Comment: Ok Interesting I changed Dim serviceWrapper = TO  Dim serviceWrapper As New, and I get the following error on the line below now Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) in method 'Public Sub Call(Of U)(aExpression As System.Func(Of T, U))' cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.

Comment: VB.NET is usually more explicit than C#, especially with `Option Infer Off`, and `Option Strict On`. Try setting those, at the top of your source file. Start adding types explicitly to your statement, see when the error goes away. You may also notice issues with other parts of your code after you apply those. However, fixing them should help you avoid issues at runtime.

Comment: Neolisk- You ARE a STAR! changing the = to As and then sorting the errors has made it work! I can;t mark this as the Answer so will put it all below

Comment: Actually If you could put as answer then you get the credit and I will comment on what I changed. Thank you

Comment: I am glad that it helped. Posted as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want `Dim serviceWrapper As New` instead of `Dim serviceWrapper = New` there.

VB.NET is usually more explicit than C#, especially with `Option Infer Off`, and `Option Strict On`. Try setting those, at the top of your source file. Start adding types explicitly to your statement, see when the error goes away. You may also notice issues with other parts of your code after you apply those. However, fixing them should help you avoid issues at runtime.

Comment: Thanks changed the = to New and commented all the return value stuff back in to get rid of errors and it works. Thank you

Comment: @user1466569: Thank you for accepting as well. You can also upvote any answers you find useful. Only one answer can be accepted, however,  multiple answers can be upvoted on a question. See [more about upvoting here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Comment: Have another quick question on this...My last line now looks like this and works great  serviceWrapper.Call(Function(x) x.GetPromotionPlans(req), Function(u) u)...but I need to assign the return data (which is in u) to a local variable so I can use...how do I do this?

Comment: @user1466569: You mean the contents of this `Function(x) x.GetPromotionPlans(req)`?

Comment: No U is the data that is returned from the function call, I need this data

Comment: @user1466569: According to what I am seeing, `U` is a selector variable. The function which gets selected is `Function(x) x.GetPromotionPlans(plan)`. Anyway, you could have a variable, which saves `result` in `ServiceCaller` class. Then call that in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is in this bit of code but maybe a reference is missed in the vb project.  and you are not returning setting the returnClass in the method Call

Try setting the returnClass in an else statement to anything to see if the error goes away, and then we can go from there

Comment: In the vb.net the returnclass stuff is commented out